# Product Flavors with more than 2 dimensions

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-flavordimension

Earlier this year I released an app for a client that we used flavor dimensions with. We had

```
         Full   |  Preview
Apple  | Apple  | Apple.Preview
Orange | Orange | Orange.Preview
```

This worked perfectly. But now I need to add `Banana` to the project as another app, and things are getting messy.

In the full versions, I have some features that are shared by the existing versions that I want to be left out from the new app entirely. There are some resources that would be nice to remove as well, but since those are small files I'm not as concerned about it. I also would prefer to avoid the `Full` and `Preview` versions of `Banana`, but if I can't do that then it's ok. **What I really need to do it group some files in `Apple` and `Orange`, and others for all 3.** Kind of like making a third dimension. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

First, for your distinct file, use `productFlavors` or `Gradle`

```
    apple{
        applicationId "com.android.apple"
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_DISTINC_STUFF", "APPLE"
    }

    orange{
        applicationId "com.android.orange"
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_DISTINC_STUFF", "ORANGE"
    }

    banana{
        applicationId "com.android.banana"
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_DISTINC_STUFF", "BANANA"
    }
```

If you want to use that string, use this `BuildConfig.MY_DISTINC_STUFF`

Second, if you want to group some files that can use for 1,2 or all. You have to do this.

1. Create 3 folders under `src` folder
2. Name it as you defined in `build.gradle` (App level). Ex: folder `apple`, folder `orange`, folder `banana`. `DON'T` remove your main folder
3. If you want to use the same file for all, please add that file to `main` folder. (Don't care 3 others)
4. If you want to use different file for different folder, create 4 file that have the `same` name, but `different folder`.
5. When you run, choose the suitable `Build Variants`.

Android Runtime will decide which file have to be loaded.

Comment: How would this work for the Preview and Full extensions? Those have resources in them as well.

Comment: create same resource folder in different place: Preview and Full. But, did you try it?

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by making a third dimension: Team. I didn't think it through correctly.